# how to count the total number of row in oledbconnection in c#.net

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledb

how to count the total number of row in oledbconnection in c#.net

I want to count how many rows are present in my table.

```
                string dataReader = "SELECT count(*) from `Email_account_list`";
                OleDbCommand command_reader = new OleDbCommand(dataReader, myConnection);
                OleDbDataReader row_reader = command_reader.ExecuteReader();
```

What function i will write to fetch total number of rows present in table.

Comment: A connection has no rows. A table or query could have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `SELECT COUNT(*)` statetment is a special (SELECT) statement in that you should not use `ExecuteReader()` but instead use `int rowCount = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: This is the best method, you could also do `while(row_reader.read()) int rows= row_reader.GetInt32(0);` but using `ExecuteScalar()` is cleaner,

Answer (score 0):

Use "Select count(*) ..." first in your OleDbCommand. This will give you an idea of the number of rows you could expect in the next "Select * ...".